# Printing factorials in reverse using recursion in Java

Tags: java, recursion, factorial

I am quite new to java, and for an assignment, we were given a faulty piece of code:

class Main{

```
// pre: assume n is greater or equal 0, but smaller than 100.
// post: return n! where n!=n*(n-1)! and 0!=1.
public static long fac(int n){
    System.out.println(n);
    long t = n*fac(n-1);                
    if (n < 0) 
        return 1;       
    return t;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// this is the test code for the judge, do not modify   
public static void main(String[] arg){

    // test function
    java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
        int input_integer=scanner.nextInt();
        fac(input_integer);         
    }
    scanner.close();
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------       

}
```

I have fixed the stack overflow problem by removing the variable.

```
// pre: assume n is greater or equal 0, but smaller than 20.
// post: return n! where n!=n*(n-1)! and 0!=1.
public static long fac(int n){
    System.out.println(n);
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;
    else return fac(n-1)*n; 

}
```

For example, if I input 4, it will give me 4, 3, 2, 1 as output. Of course, this is not the actual output that I want. First, the output i am looking for is in reverse order, and the actual factorials, not just n. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

(As an example output: 3 --> 1, 1, 2, 6)

Answer (score 1):

Just print it **after** you calculate it.

```
public static long fac(int n) {
    long f = (n <= 1 ? 1 : fac(n - 1) * n);
    System.out.println(f);
    return f;
}
```

If you print it **before** you recurse you will be printing the values as you climb up the recursion tree. The values will therefore appear in reverse order. `fac(`**n**`=fac(`**n-1**`...`.

If you print it **after** you recurse you will be printing the values as you step out of the recursion tree. The values will therefore appear in forward order. `fac(`**1**`*fac(`**2**`...`.

Comment: @NinaHain - It is important that you understand the concept - it is very useful when you use recursion for walking around in tree structures.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your stack overflow wasn't because you had a variable, it was
   because you performed the recursive call *prior* to checking for the
   terminating condition.
2. Printing the result after the recursive call, rather than the argument prior to the recursive call, will do what you want.

Here's what it looks like if you stick with your original vars and use of an `if` statement:

```
public static long fac(int n){
  if (n < 0) 
    return 1;       
  long t = n * fac(n-1);                
  System.out.println(t);
  return t;
}
```